# How to get all parents until a certain parent is reached

Tags: jquery, traversal, jquery-traversing

I need something in-between the functionality of `.closest()` and `.parents()`. I am applying some CSS to all parents of a certain element up to a certain parent. Right now I'm `while` looping up, but it seems like there is a better way to do this.

```
var goUp = $(".distant-child");
while(!goUp.hasClass("ancestor-to-stop-at")){
    goUp.css("height","100%");
    goUp = goUp.parent();
}
```

I'd rather do something like one of these:

```
$(".distant-child").closest(".ancestor-to-stop-at").css("height","100%"); //won't work because .closest() only returns the top ancestor
$(".distant-child").parents(".ancestor-to-stop-at").css("height","100%"); //won't work because .parents() doesn't take this parameter and won't stop at the specified element.
```

How can I achieve this without a `while` loop?

Comment: Are you looking for http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/?

Comment: *scuffs shoe in dirt* ...yes...

Comment: When you use JavaScript for messing with CSS directly, it is usually considered to be a *code smell* (unless you are doing animations).

Comment: It's unavoidable because I'm working on top of plugins that are already doing this to excess. I had a perfect CSS-only solution that is ruined by tons of competing `style=""` changes being made by these stupid plugins.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use jquery [`parentsUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) function

```
$(".distant-child").parentsUntil(".ancestor-to-stop-at").css("height","100%");
```

Comment: @brentonstrine: That awkward moment when your "I'm an idiot" comment gets more upvotes than the answer itself.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Yes, but if those upvoters are like me, then they have probably had that exact same "I'm an idiot" feeling ;-)

Comment: The upvote for the answer is obvious. 
The upvote for the comment is to show support to the OP :)